# What is this Unity Error? Addr2Line failure

Tags: unity-game-engine, il2cpp, addr2line

Suddenly I have this error and I dont know how to solve.

1. I have this error on PC

/..........................................................
Addr2Line failure

Scripting Backend: il2cpp

Build Type: release

CPU: arm64-v8a

---

Addr2Line failure

Scripting Backend: il2cpp

Build Type: release

CPU: arm64-v8a

C:/Program Files/Android/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line.exe -C -f -p -e C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2019.1.0f2\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Variations\il2cpp\release\Symbols\arm64-v8a\libunity.so 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000

stderr[
C:/Program Files/Android/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line.exe: 'C:\Program': No such file
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 1

/.............................................................

2. I have this error after built android app.

error : currently not available il2cpp line: -1

Comment: your ndk version must be r13b not r16b,Unity3d require it,Try download ndk r13 and try build again

Comment: Thank you for reply. I just downloaded 13b and tried to set it but I cannot use 13b. It says that "NDK 13.1.3345770 detected. Unity requires NDK r16b(64bit)"